# setting up doorkeeper on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

I am following the railscast (#353 OAuth with Doorkeeper pro) and am stuck in setting up doorkeeper. Please see below:

1. In gemfile, I put gem 'doorkeeper' and then run bundle to install it
2. Next, I run the `rails generate doorkeeper:migration`, followed by `rake db:migrate`

I see a couple of rows of `'create_table'` and `'add_index'` as expected.

Here's the problem:

In my folder 'initializers', there is no `doorkeeper.rb` file. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this before you run `doorkeeper:migration`

```
rails generate doorkeeper:install
```